# How to load native library securely in Android?

Tags: java, android, security, android-ndk

I'm wondering about security implications between System.loadLibrary and System.load in Android.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylib");
}
```

Relying on the calling system to help locate things (via System.loadLibrary method) can lead to the system provide a file that wasn't intended to be loaded by the application. If an attacker can place a file in a location that falls under the search, then the attacker can inject arbitrary code into the application and execute it.

If you specify the exact path, you have the ability to protect the loaded file through things like file permissions, etc.

The question is: how can we specify the full path for an NDK library in such a way that this path is valid for every Android version/device.

Answer (score 4):

`System.loadLibrary` is a high-level method designed for ease of use: as far as I know, it searches through the `lib` folder of your app (on the Android filesystem), which corresponds to the `libs` folder of your Eclipse project.

This means that, in order to mess up with your app by loading the wrong library using `System.loadLibrary`, the attacker would have to be able to either override your own libs in this `lib` folder, or to add a library with the same name in this `lib` folder in some way. I have absolutely no idea if that is possible (I hope and guess not!), but assuming it is, this means that the `lib` folder can't be considered safe.

This implies that in order to protect your app against such an attack, you'll want to put your library files somewhere else, and thus that you have your own logic for writing the library files on disk, somewhere. In such a case, somewhere in this logic, you have your hand on the absolute path of your libs.

Having the path to your libs, you can add your library using [`System.load`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) which takes the full path to the library to load as argument.

In short, 2 options:

- either the `lib` folder is attackable, you can't put your libraries there, so you have your own logic for storing them and you can load them using `System.load`
- or the `lib`  folder is indeed safe, and then there is no risk of attack on it: you can use the more standard `System.loadLibrary`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can we specify the full path for an NDK library in such a way that this path is valid for every Android version/device?

Comment: Edited my answer for more details.

Comment: Not exactly - I suspect that System.loadLibrary() will search some system directories in addition to the app's lib folder.  However, anyone who can attack these can presumably attack the lib folder as well (or else the app is being run on a severely broken device which has writable system directories).  You are unlikely to find a location any safer than your own app's lib folder, especially as that folder is not even writable by your app, wheras anywhere else you could put it would have to be.